# Error creating bean with name 'grailsEvents'

Tags: grails, grails-2.4

I'm trying to migrate grails to 2.4.4 version and I'm getting this error: No idea what could be the problem.

Some suggestion is welcome, thanks in advance.

```
Error |
2015-12-15 10:45:47,097 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'grailsEvents': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'grailsEventsPublisher' while setting bean property 'grailsEventsPublisher'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsEventsPublisher': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'persistenceInterceptor' while setting bean property 'persistenceInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'persistenceInterceptor' is defined
Message: Error creating bean with name 'grailsEvents': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'grailsEventsPublisher' while setting bean property 'grailsEventsPublisher'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsEventsPublisher': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'persistenceInterceptor' while setting bean property 'persistenceInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'persistenceInterceptor' is defined
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsEventsPublisher': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'persistenceInterceptor' while setting bean property 'persistenceInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'persistenceInterceptor' is defined
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'persistenceInterceptor' is defined
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Comment: I think it can be during old plugins that don't suport newest version. Try to do "dependency-report" or google all your plugins and look into versions that they suport(the same you can find in plugin info file(sorry but forgot how it named))